# import but dll was not loaded

Tags: c#, mef

I have a class exported and in a different part of the code it is imported.

```
[Import]
public IEnumerable<IRTAOperatorErrorNotifications> RTAOperatorErrorNotifications
{
    get { return m_RTAOperatorErrorNotifications; }
}
```

Now the DLL were the class resides is loaded into the application conditionally and in most cases it won't exist, so I'm wondering will this cause the program to crash if the DLL doesn't exist?
  What I want is for the object to simply be set to null if the DLL isn't there so I can check and do the right thing. Is there a way to conditionally import so the value is set to null if the class isn't loaded?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Suggested changes: since it is an `IEnumerable` you need to use `ImportMany`. `AllowDefault = true` allows code to set it `NULL` when no import was found.

```
[ImportMany(AllowDefault = true)]
public IEnumerable<IRTAOperatorErrorNotifications> RTAOperatorErrorNotifications { get; private set; }
```